# Add images in select tag rather than input tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, dropdown

I'm trying to achieve a drop down using "select-tag", but the dropdown in the [referal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB8rv.jpg) has image and content aligned like a table. I've gone through the FAQ's and can't find any related answer. As you can see when you select something it is directly showing the text written in it, as it should show the image and the content. Please help me out.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#search_iva').click(function(){
   $('.drp-result').toggle();
 
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(images/mac.jpg);
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.79);
  color: #ffffff;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.detail {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 450px;
}
/*
.detail:after {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: Fontawesome;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
 }*/

.detail input, .detail textarea, .detail select {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

option {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.detail textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
}

.detail label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.detail .inputBar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.detail .inputBar:before,
.detail .inputBar:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 2px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
}

select {
  outline: none;
  
}





.drp-result:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: "\25b2";
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: -8px;
    left: 597px;
    color: tan;
}

.drp-result {
  display: none;
}

.col {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-right: 2%;
  text-align:center;
}

.col2 {width: 16.6666666667%; vertical-align:middle;}
.col5 {width: 37%;}

.list-item p {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script rel="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>


 <div class="container">
    
    <h2>Search what you like</h2>
    
    
    <div class="detail"><select id="search_iva" type="text"><label>I Want to see...</label>
      <option>hello1</option>
     
      <option><div class="list-item" style="margin: 30px 0;">
         <div class="col col2"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/eSOTqQ/1.jpg"></div>
         <div class="col col5"><h4>small doggy</h4></div>
         <div class="col col5"><p>Adopt it and express your love</p></div>
      </div>
        
      </option>
        <option>hello3</option>
      
      <span class="inputBar"></span><!--inputBar-->
 </div>
     
  
 
  <div class="drp-result">
    <div class="result-inner">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
      
      <div class="list-item" style="margin: 30px 0;">
      <a><div class="col col2"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/eSOTqQ/1.jpg"></div>
         <div class="col col5"><h4>small doggy</h4></div>
         <div class="col col5"><p>Adopt it and express your love</p></div>
      </a></div>
      
      <div class="list-item" style="margin: 30px 0;">
      <a><div class="col col2"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/gmkux5/3.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col col5"><h4>women</h4></div>
         <div class="col col5"><p>A picture of laughing women</p></div>
      </a></div>
      
      <div class="list-item" style="margin: 30px 0;">
      <a><div class="col col2"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/bWVoPk/2.jpg"></div>
        <div class="col col5"><h4>pomolion</h4></div>
         <div class="col col5"><p>A rare breed puppy</p></div>
      </a></div>
      
      <div class="list-item" style="margin: 30px 0;">
      <a><div class="col col2"><img style="width: 100%;" src="https://image.ibb.co/eSOTqQ/1.jpg"></div>
         <div class="col col5"><h4>small doggy</h4></div>
         <div class="col col5"><p>Adopt it and express your love</p></div>
      </a></div>
      </div> 
    
    </div><!--container--> 
  </div>
```

Comment: [smallimage] text . is it in this format you need?

Comment: yes but medium size image would be good as the referral image i linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want isn't possible. You would have to simulate a select box. Please see example below.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function() {
  $(this).next(".options").toggleClass("open");
});

$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  $(".selected").html($(this).find("span").html());
  $(".options").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 25%;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.options.open {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li>img {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
  <ul class="options">
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/00ff00"><span>Option 1</span></li>
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/ff0000"><span>Option 2</span></li>
    <li class="option"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/0000ff"><span>Option 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Best solotuion is that you could use jquery plugin called [ddslick](https://github.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick)

You can create a dropdown list such as,

[image]

Add the images you want and create *select/option* list as,

Something like this would work only in firefox

```
<select>
<option value="smalldog1" style="background-image:url(https://image.ibb.co/eSOTqQ/1.jpg);">Small Dog 1</option>
<option value="smalldog2"  style="background-image:url(https://image.ibb.co/gmkux5/3.jpg);">Small Dog 2</option>
<option value="smalldog3" style="background-image:url(https://image.ibb.co/bWVoPk/2.jpg);">Small Dog 3</option>
<option value="smalldog4"  style="background-image:url(https://image.ibb.co/eSOTqQ/1.jpg);">Small Dog 4</option>
</select>
```